# How do I parse a file using Perl's XML::SAX?

Tags: xml, perl, sax

I am trying `XML::SAX` parser for parsing XML file. XML file is shown below,

```
            <message>
                <c1>
                    <rrcConnectionSetupComplete>
                        <rrc-TransactionIdentifier>2</rrc-TransactionIdentifier>
                        <criticalExtensions>
                            <c1>
                                <rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8>
                                    <selectedPLMN-Identity> 1 </selectedPLMN-Identity>
                                    <dedicatedInfoNAS> 07410109014290112345671000028020000f0 </dedicatedInfoNAS>
                                </rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8>
                            </c1>
                        </criticalExtensions>
                    </rrcConnectionSetupComplete>
                </c1>
            </message>
```

Perl code is shown below,

```
use strict;

use XML::SAX;
use MySAXHandler;

my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => MySAXHandler->new);

$parser->parse_uri("uL-DCCH-Message.xml");

my $rrc_trans_identifier = $parser->{'c1'}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete'}->{'rrc-TransactionIdentifier'};
print "rrc_trans_id :: $rrc_trans_identifier\n";

my $selected_plmn_id = $parser->{c1}->{rrcConnectionSetupComplete}->{criticalExtensions}->{c1}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8'}->{'selectedPLMN-Identity'};
print "plmn identity :: $selected_plmn_id\n";

my $rrc_dedicated_info_nas = $parser->{c1}->{rrcConnectionSetupComplete}->{criticalExtensions}->{c1}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8'}->{dedicatedInfoNAS};
print "dedicated info nas :: $rrc_dedicated_info_nas\n";
```

When i run this code, i am getting output as,

```
Can't locate MySAXHandler.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at sax.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sax.pl line 4.
```

I installed XML::SAX from CPAN, but still it shows some module missing error.

My questions are,

1. Does it needs anyother modules to be installed?
2. To access the values in XML file, the procedure i am following is correct?

For example:

```
my $rrc_trans_identifier = $parser->{'c1'}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete'}->{'rrc-TransactionIdentifier'};
print "rrc_trans_id :: $rrc_trans_identifier\n";
```

Comment: You might want to stop a bit to learn Perl. It seems that all of your questions are related to copying and pasting code examples, not understanding what they do, then asking here as soon as something doesn't work out. That's not a good strategy for success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your own `MySAXHandler` (the clue is in the name!).

See the [SAX::Intro](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-SAX/view/lib/XML/SAX/Intro.pod) documentation for more details.

**Update:** Replaced search.cpan.org link with metacpan.org.